# How to get the first four decimal numbers in Javascript using math.ceil?

Tags: javascript

Currently have the following javascript code:

```
div.html( Drupal.t("Date")+": "+d.date+"</br>"+Drupal.t("Value")+": " + (d.value))
```

Value that i'm getting is  0.1651859999999985 . I wanna round it off to the first four decimal numbers. Any help? I tried `Math.ceil(d.value*10)/10)` but it was only getting the first decimal :( Any help? I wanna get 0.1652

Comment: `Math.ceil(d.value*(10**<n>))/10**<n>` where n is the number of decimal places needed

Comment: Worked so well! @SajalPreetSingh

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please do check the indicated question "How to round up a number in Javascript?" -> more generic and has more perspectives / answers.

Comment: @SajalPreetSingh it wasn't working :( 823.124148336763 is converting to 823.1242 instead of just 823.1241

Comment: 10**<n> actually means 10 raised to the power of <n>. So 10**4 means 10000.

Comment: @MilkMagic in that case you should be using `Math.round`

Answer (score 0):

Should be `Math.ceil(d.value*10000)/10000` 
example:

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(0.1683123*10000)/10000)
console.log(Math.ceil(823.124148336763*10000)/10000) // round up to the ceiling
console.log(Math.floor(823.124148336763*10000)/10000) // round down to the floor
console.log(Math.round(823.124148336763*10000)/10000) // below .5 -> down, above .5 -> up
```

Comment: It was working, but now you've broken it??

Comment: Yes, I did, it appears I have misread the requirement of the first decimal digits to mean that s/he needs just the digits like 1683 in the example above.

Comment: @BogdanBiv What's your correct answer? 823.124148336763*(10**4))/10**4) isn't working :(